# Northwind - List of top ten employees

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have another trouble with my SQL queries.

My task is to create a list of top 10 employees, with the most sales in 1997.
So far I have this, simple query that shows me list of employees and which order they've sold.

```
SELECT  
    Orders.EmployeeID,
    Orders.OrderID
FROM
    Employees
JOIN 
    Orders ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
ORDER BY 
    Orders.EmployeeID;
```

Now I want to group up those numbers, I need to know how many sales each employee did in 1997. How to do that?

Comment: GROUP BY, and FETCH FIRST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the results that you need without `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` if you order by results of a subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM Employees e
ORDER BY (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Sales s
    WHERE s.EmployeeId=e.EmployeeId
      AND DATEPART(year, o.OrderDate)=1997
) DESC
```

This yields top ten employees by the number of sales transactions.

If you need anything from `Sales`, say, the count, you would need to go the `GROUP BY` route:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM (
    SELECT e.EmployeeId, COUNT(*) AS SalesCount
    FROM Employees e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders o ON o.EmployeeId=e.EmployeeId
                            AND DATEPART(year, o.OrderDate)=1997
    GROUP BY e.EmployeeId
) groups
ORDER BY SalesCount DESC
```

Comment: Good, something like that. But is there any chance to add number of sales in that year? Like Employee 1 = 20 sales, Employee 2 = 18?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT EmployeeId,COUNT(*) as cn,
       DENSE_RANK(ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
FROM orders
WHERE DATEPART(year,OrderDate)=1997
GROUP BY EmployeeId
) 
SELECT e.*,COALESCE(o.cn,0) AS CountOrders
FROM Employees e
LEFT JOIN CTE o
ON e.EmployeeId=o.EmployeeId
WHERE o.rn<=10
```

Answer (score 0):

It can reduce to this

```
SELECT  top(10) EmployeeID, count(*) as cnt
FROM  Orders 
group by EmployeeID 
ORDER BY count(*) desc;
```